# Send ASPX.net attribute towards angular in the backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, angular

How do I connect the 'index.aspx.cs - public string getContactID() { return 1; }' to the app.component.ts

this event needs to work any method would be fine.

the whole project is inside visual studio 2015 Web Api

---

app\app.component.ts

```
SomethingClick() {
     ID:number = 'index.aspx.cs'.getContactID();
}
```

---

Index.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="CA_CopyLine.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <base href="/"/>
     <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>

     <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
      <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21?main=browser"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"> 
</script>

     <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
     <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
     <script>
       System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Index.aspx.cs

```
public partial class index     {

    [WebMethod]
    public string getContactID()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

app\app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app/app.component.css']

 })
 export class AppComponent { }

SomethingClick() {
     ID:number = 'index.aspx.cs'.getContactID();
}
```

Comment: If you're using Web API, you might want to actually use Web API (via an `ApiController`) instead of `WebMethod` web services.

Comment: The thing is, this project is a Web API the aspx is for using DLL files

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a http call to the webmethod to get the details .Also you need to make the WebMethod static . Please go thru this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) to get more information. Though in the link call is made from jquery the concept is the same from angular js also.

From the component.ts make a http call to `index.aspx\getContactID` .